# How can I hide a method from Java reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a Java class with 3 methods.

**My questions are:**

1-How can I hide the methods from being enumerated by a Java reflection?

2-How can I hide one method of the three methods at least from being enumerated by a Java reflection?

Comment: If we knew why you wanted this, perhaps we could suggest a viable alternative.

Answer (score 2):

If reflection does not do what you want, change it ;-) Seriously, you can use a dynamically loaded java agent to retransform the reflection classes and put in a few ifs to hide your methods.

This [this blog post](http://ruediste.github.io/bytecode/2017/02/25/lambda-inspection.html) uses this technique to alter the behaviour of the `LambdaMetafactory`. Changing the reflection classes is analogous.

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide *anything* from Reflection.

This has amusingly terrible consequences in some cases. For instance, an old version of Android had an IntegerCache class inside Integer where it cached boxed versions of the first 128 integers. It was private, but with Reflection you could modify this to highly amusing effect (making the boxed versions of integers not equal to the unboxed ones, and since boxing is often implicit...)

That said, you could use lambdas. Those are still reachable by reflection, but with obnoxiously non-obvious names.

Another thing you could do is put your secret function in native code which inspects the state of Java using the JNI to determine if this call is allowed. Bit of an evil hack but it's probably the best you can do :/